# Ramdomize selected column in Excel

Tags: excel, random, numbers

I am new to this formula stuffs in excel. After searched on the internet I found this `=RAND()` function which I am using to randomize a couple of numbers. Like the one on the image.

By default, pressing `Ctrl D` or `F9` is randomizing all the numbers in the worksheet.

Is it possible to select a **group of cells** and randomize only those and not changing the other columns?

[image]

I am using the `SUM` function for all the columns. I do not want the output in a negative number. I would like it to be positive (like the 2nd and the 3rd column). I am using a function `=RANDBETWEEN(-3, 9)`. When I refresh using `F9` sometimes I get a negative number, so instead of refreshing (which changes all the column), I want to select that group of cells and randomize till I get a positive number. I have around 50 to 100 columns and need to refresh at the same time.

Does it make sense?

[image]

Comment: `RAND()` will be recalculated always so, what are you trying?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego  I have updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the range and insert at the same position. After inserting, press `Ctrl` and select the option to only keep actual values from the menu that opens.

Shortcuts to do this: Select the range with randoms, press `Ctrl+C`, press `Shift+F10`, press `V`

Comment: I do not want the actual value, this will randomize it every time I open the file. The point is not to get a negative number when I add the cells, please see the updated question.